# deploy angular app in spring-boot (finds index.html, but not the js files)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, war

I have the following setup for my application:

```
application.war
  application.rest.jar
  application.core.jar
  application.frontend.jar
    public
      index.html
      assets
        myapp.js
        ...
```

When I start my application I find the index.html file, but I get a 404 for files under assets. When I try to go in to the folder Chrome downloads a assets file that is 0 bytes.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? According to spring it seems this would be enough? (https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Can you show us your web configuration ? 
You should try to check you files size in target directory. It can be a maven filtering problem.

Comment: hmm, maybe this is the problem, I thought you did not need much of a web-configuration to run this? I use the default spring web.xml, so I don't have one. Must I have some configuration for this to work?

My build is correct, when I unarchive my war the files seems to be correct.

Comment: I'm stupid, sorry.... I forgot the EnableWebMvc annotation.... thanks for the help @MartinChoraine